# Multiple mouse pointers unstable

Tags: debian, gnome, multi-monitor, gnome-shell, multi-pointer

(Running Debian 8.5, Gnome 3.14.1)

I purchased a secondary monitor which is a touch screen. I do Android development, so the plan was to keep my main (non-touch) monitor dedicated to code and have an android emulator on the second monitor and interact with it by touch.

The problem I'm running into is that touching on the second screen moves the mouse cursor to where I touch, which defeats half of the purpose of a touch screen for me (the other half is that the emulator doesn't support multi-touch inputs, but I've accepted that). I realized what I needed was to have two separate mouse pointers, and followed [instructions on doing that with xinput.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multi-pointer_X#Software_support)

This works, but not well. The second mouse blinks constantly (I believe it's confused about which monitor it's on) and simple operations fail. Touching on a window's title bar to drag it will result in the mouse-pointer starting to drag the window, e.g. Eventually either both mice will become invisible or the system will crash.

I was curious if there was anything I could do to make this stable?